# operator overloading Fractions

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

```
#include"Fraction.h"

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


Fraction operator*(const Fraction& left, const Fraction& right)
{
    int newNum = left.getNum() * right.getNum();
    int newDenom = right.getDenom() * left.getDenom();

    Fraction result(newNum, newDenom); //Error is here, cannot convert from Fraction to int
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    Fraction a(3,4);
    Fraction b(1,2);
    Fraction c = a * b;

    cout << c << endl;
}
```

This is my code here, we just started doing operator overloads this week and I'm quite stuck.

The main obviously does not work but that's the input I want to pass through, but I don't understand the error I'm getting. Can anyone break this down for me just a little? I'd appreciate it.

```
//This is my Header file for anyone that wants to see it

#ifndef FRACTION_H
#define FRACTION_H

class Fraction
{

public:

    Fraction(int numParam, int denomParam);

    void setNum(int numParam);
    int getNum() const;

    void setDenom(int denomParam);
    int getDenom() const;

private:
    int num;
    int denom;

};

#endif
```

Comment: I'm struggling to see how that code could produce that error.

Comment: I don't see where this code fails. Can you show us your constructor `Fraction(int, int)`?

Comment: We need to see `Fraction.h`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz we don't, see my answer. Well we kind of do, do we want to fix it or help him with the error?

Comment: The code works fine given a properly defined `Fraction`. See [this](http://ideone.com/l7YyGO). Where is the rest of the code for your `Fraction`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't know how to display fractions, add this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Fraction& frac) {
    stream<<"Do something with frac here, like output num/denom\n";
    return stream;
}
```

Although it isn't whining about your cout line now, it will when you fix this error, because it doesn't know how to do a << on a std::ostream and a Fraction.

**NOT THIS - from original answer**

Your error is likely one of those "used from here" error markers, it's telling you where it got confused, it probably tried to print frac as an int.... yeah.

**ACTUAL ANSWER**

When you say `Fraction A = B*C;` the compiler sees something like `Fraction A = AnotherFraction;` it can do `Fraction A;` (default constructor) followed by `Fraction::operator=(Fraction&);` or it could use r-values in this case (move assignments) from the temporary you return.

C++ allows one level of implicit casting, somewhere you have "Fraction::Fraction(int);" - a constructor that takes an int, C++ wants to convert your Fraction to an int, and construct a new Fraction with that int.

it is whining because it can't. Give it a copy constructor, see rule of 3 (now rule of 5), you should always have your assignment operator and copy constructor, never just one (without VERY good reason) and with C++11 your assignment r-value operator and "" constructor.

**In closing**

we need your constructors, that one level of implict casting is giving you errors that appear weird because "why int" but for some reason C++ wants to use Fraction::Fraction(int), which I know exist from what you've said, it's upset because it can't go fraction->int (it wants to do fraction->int->fraction)

**Note**

This is why C++ has a heavy learning curve, because it is so powerful (what it does with implict conversions is without a doubt a good thing!) you can get errors that tell you more where it got confused than what is actually wrong. Like when you have an operator<< with a typo and it tries to match it to one of the standard operator<<, you get like a 4 page reason about why what you said is wrong and how it can't instantiate a certain (unrelated in a human's view) template.

**Addendum**

```
template<class T>
class Ratio {
public:
    Ratio(): top(0), bottom(1) {}
    Ratio(T& from): top(from), bottom(1) {}
    Ratio(T& top, T& bottom): top(top), bottom(bottom) {}
    Ratio(T&& from): top(from), bottom(1) {}
    Ratio(T&& top, T&& bottom): top(top), bottom(bottom) {}
    Ratio& operator=(Ratio& from) {
        top = from.top;
        bottom = from.bottom;
    }
    Ratio& operator=(Ratio&& from) {
        top = from.top;
        bottom = from.bottom;
    }
    Ratio(const Ratio& from): top(from.top), bottom(from.bottom) {}
    Ratio(Ratio&& from): top(from.top), bottom(from.bottom) {}
    ~Ratio() {}

    const T& getTop() const { return top; }
    const T& getBottom() const { return bottom; }
    T& getTop() { return top; }
    T& getBottom() { return bottom; }


    Ratio operator*(const Ratio& rhs) const { //we are the left hand side
        T newTop = rhs.top*this->top;
        T newBottom = rhs.bottom*this->bottom;
        Ratio result(newTop,newBottom);
        return result;
    }
private:
    T top;
    T bottom;
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Ratio<T>& ratio) {
    stream<<ratio.getTop()<<"/"<<ratio.getBottom();
    return stream;
}

typedef Ratio<int> Fraction;

int main(int,char**) {
    Fraction a;
    std::cout<<"A: "<<a<<"\n";
    Fraction b(1);
    std::cout<<"B: "<<b<<"\n";
    Fraction c = a*b;
    std::cout<<"A*B=C: "<<c<<"\n";
    Fraction d(5,3);
    std::cout<<"Look! "<<d*d<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

That works!

Comment: The OP says the error comes from `Fraction result(newNum, newDenom);`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed response, its all a bit over my head now at the moment. My constructor was Fraction(int numParam, int denomParam) for everyone that wanted to see it.

Comment: @user2757842 click edit and put more than just that in there. (Edit on your question) Also remember to upvote and tick as accepted and such, so many new users don't do that.

Comment: This is baloney.  `Fraction A = AnotherFraction;` is *always* copy-initialization, never assignment.  The compiler **cannot** choose to do default initialization followed by `operator=`.

Comment: @AlecTeal: Copy elision means avoiding a call of a copy constructor.  For example, `Fraction A = 1;` means `Fraction temp{1}; Fraction A{std::move(temp)};`, but copy elision allows the compiler to do just `Fraction A{1};`, but it still has to do an access check on the (move) copy-constructor.  Copy elision won't cause a call to an assignment operator.  Section 8.5 p15-17 and 12.8 p31-32 are the relevant rules in the Standard.

Comment: @user2757842 check the answer now, that works. Enjoy it. That is "good code" the only issue with it that for the multiplicative identity and additive identity (1 and 0 respectively) it tries to construct T (an int for fraction) from 1 or 0. But anyway! This is good code, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

ok I think I know what the problem was. 
In the header file the constructor was not defined so that when he ran the program it would not pick up that the fraction class took in two ints.
Therefore by defining the constructor the program was allowed to run!

Basically this was not in it.

```
Fraction::Fraction(int numeratorParam, int denomeratorParam)
{

numerator = numeratorPram;

denumerator = denumeratorParam;

}
```